# BGP - Peering points vs BGP speakers?

Tags: bgp, peering

I'm taking a networks class and am a little confused about the role of BGP speakers vs peering points and I'm having trouble finding consistent / reliable resources by using google.

Can anyone give a pretty simple explaination of the concept of peering points and BGP speakers and how they are different / the same?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Peering Points are just points where two autonmous networks connect to each other, like at an [Internet Exchange](http://www.bgp4.as/internet-exchanges), but not limited to only public internet.

BGP speakers are the actual devices that can participate in BGP. This includes routers which are carrying traffic, as well as route reflector servers which help ease BGP peering or are used for information gathering.

2 BGP speakers would connect at a peering point.